# Applescript - Can't Get Text of TextEdit or variable not defined

Tags: excel, file, directory, applescript, textedit

I'm trying to open all files in a folder and append the contents into an Excel file. Every file is a text file and I can use the text, and paragraph attributes and loop through to append them to a cell. Then I use a few if statements to delete headers and end of the text lines. Then I use text item delimiters to get specific information to cells.

The problem is, I sometimes get different errors; one of the computers I tried outright gives "TextEdit can't get text of document 1" while one of the test computers works after the second try, and another computer sometimes gives "variable fileContent is not defined" I have no idea why I receive this error, or what causes it.

I thought it might be because of a desync between the script and the files, so instead of using it on the server, I got them on my desktop. No cigar. I tried adding a delay of one second, but still, it sometimes works, and sometimes does not.

Further info:
File count varies between 15 to 40. The Excel spreadsheet is empty at first. Unsure if I can or should share example files, but you can find them here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7c79b740c876564c740fcb16c345716b20230317182515/5c4114

Here's the code:

```
set errorMsg to "Unless you canceled the app, starting from item one, please try the following steps:" & return & return & "Retry running the app" & return & return & "If restarting the app does not work: Quit TextEdit and Excel apps, and restart both of them" & return & return & "If the two above steps don't work: Use fewer files" & return & return & "If none of the above work: Continue manually"

tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to every file of (choose folder)
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set thisWorkbook to make new workbook


tell application "TextEdit"
    
    
    set thisFile to 1
    
    repeat with theFile from 1 to count of items in myFiles
        
        set theFile to item thisFile of myFiles
        
        try
            
            open theFile
            delay 1
            set fileContent to text of document 1
            
            
        on error
            
            display dialog errorMsg
            
        end try
        
        set currentParagraph to 1
        set reverseRow to 1
        
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            
            set lastRow to (first row index of (get end (last cell of column 3 of active sheet) direction toward the top))
            
            set currentRow to lastRow + 1
            
            repeat with currentParagraph from 1 to count of paragraphs of fileContent
                
                
                set value of cell ("C" & currentRow) to paragraph currentParagraph of fileContent
                set value of cell ("A" & currentRow) to second word of fileContent
                
                set currentParagraph to currentParagraph + 1
                set currentRow to currentRow + 1
                
                
            end repeat
            
            --DELETES END OF TX FILLER PROGRAM AND HEADER ROW WITH WEEKDAY/DATE
            --DATES WILL BE ADDED LATER
            
            
            repeat with reverseRow from ((count of rows in used range of active sheet) + 1) to 1 by -1
                
                
                if string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "PONIEDZIAŁEK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "WTOREK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "ŚRODA" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "CZWARTEK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "PIĄTEK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "SOBOTA" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "NIEDZIELA" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "06:00 Zakończenie dnia" then
                    
                    delete row reverseRow
                    --display dialog "deleted row " & reverseRow
                    
                end if
                
            end repeat
            
            
            
        end tell
        
        tell document 1 to close
        
        
        set thisFile to thisFile + 1
        
        
        
    end repeat
    
    
    
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        
        
        set currentRow to 2
        
        set lastRow to (first row index of (get end (last cell of column 3 of active sheet) direction toward the top))
        
        repeat with currentRow from 2 to lastRow
            
            set theText to string value of cell ("C" & currentRow)
            set {oldDelims, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ";"}
            set theColumns to text items of theText
            
            set value of cell ("J" & currentRow) to item 1 of theColumns
            
            
            
            set theText to string value of cell ("J" & currentRow)
            set {oldDelims, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "-"}
            set theColumns to text items of theText
            
            set value of cell ("K" & currentRow) to item 1 of theColumns
            
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
            
            set theText to string value of cell ("K" & currentRow)
            set charCount to get count of characters of theText
            
            set theChars to text 1 thru 5 of theText
            set value of cell ("B" & currentRow) to theChars
            
            set value of cell ("N" & currentRow) to "=REPLACE(" & "K" & currentRow & ",1,5, " & quote & space & quote & ")"
            set value of cell ("C" & currentRow) to get value of cell ("N" & currentRow)
            set value of cell ("C" & currentRow) to value of cell ("K" & currentRow)
            
            set currentRow to currentRow + 1
            
        end repeat
        
        set value of range "J:J" to ""
        set value of range "K:K" to ""
        set value of range "N:N" to ""
        
    end tell
    
end tell

display dialog "Done!"
```

Edit:

Per Mockman's suggestions, I've altered the code. I'm afraid it's still giving the same error: the variable fileContent is not defined.

I've changed the delay from 0.4 to 1, didn't do anything. I've changed it to 2, now it's back again to 'sometimes works, sometimes doesn't' state.

Here's the updated code:

```
set errorMsg to "Unless you canceled the app, starting from item one, please try the following steps:" & return & return & "Retry running the app" & return & return & "If restarting the app does not work: Quit TextEdit and Excel apps, and restart both of them" & return & return & "If the two above steps don't work: Use fewer files" & return & return & "If none of the above work: Continue manually"

tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to every file of (choose folder)
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set thisWorkbook to make new workbook
delay 0.4


tell application "TextEdit"
    
    
    --set thisFile to 1
    
    repeat with theFile in myFiles
        
        --set theFile to item thisFile of myFiles
        
        try
            
            open theFile
            delay 2
            set fileContent to text of document 1
            
            
            
            (*
on error
            
            display dialog errorMsg
*)
            
            
        end try
        
        set currentParagraph to 1
        set reverseRow to 1
        
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            
            set lastRow to (first row index of (get end (last cell of column 3 of active sheet) direction toward the top))
            
            set currentRow to lastRow + 1
            
            repeat with currentParagraph from 1 to count of paragraphs of fileContent
                
                
                set value of cell ("C" & currentRow) to paragraph currentParagraph of fileContent
                set value of cell ("A" & currentRow) to second word of fileContent
                
                set currentParagraph to currentParagraph + 1
                set currentRow to currentRow + 1
                
                
            end repeat
            
            --DELETES END OF TX FILLER PROGRAM AND HEADER ROW WITH WEEKDAY/DATE
            --DATES WILL BE ADDED LATER
            
            
            repeat with reverseRow from ((count of rows in used range of active sheet) + 1) to 1 by -1
                
                
                if string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "PONIEDZIAŁEK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "WTOREK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "ŚRODA" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "CZWARTEK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "PIĄTEK" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "SOBOTA" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "NIEDZIELA" or string value of cell ("C" & reverseRow) contains "06:00 Zakończenie dnia" then
                    
                    delete row reverseRow
                    --display dialog "deleted row " & reverseRow
                    
                end if
                
            end repeat
            
            
            
        end tell
        
        tell document 1 to close
        
        
        --set thisFile to thisFile + 1
        
        
        
    end repeat
    
    
    
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        
        
        set currentRow to 2
        
        set lastRow to (first row index of (get end (last cell of column 3 of active sheet) direction toward the top))
        
        repeat with currentRow from 2 to lastRow
            
            set theText to string value of cell ("C" & currentRow)
            set {oldDelims, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ";"}
            set theColumns to text items of theText
            
            set value of cell ("J" & currentRow) to item 1 of theColumns
            
            
            
            set theText to string value of cell ("J" & currentRow)
            set {oldDelims, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "-"}
            set theColumns to text items of theText
            
            set value of cell ("K" & currentRow) to item 1 of theColumns
            
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
            
            set theText to string value of cell ("K" & currentRow)
            set charCount to get count of characters of theText
            
            set theChars to text 1 thru 5 of theText
            set value of cell ("B" & currentRow) to theChars
            
            set value of cell ("N" & currentRow) to "=REPLACE(" & "K" & currentRow & ",1,5, " & quote & space & quote & ")"
            set value of cell ("C" & currentRow) to get value of cell ("N" & currentRow)
            set value of cell ("C" & currentRow) to value of cell ("K" & currentRow)
            
            set currentRow to currentRow + 1
            
        end repeat
        
        set value of range "J:J" to ""
        set value of range "K:K" to ""
        set value of range "N:N" to ""
        
    end tell
    
end tell

display dialog "Done!"
```

Comment: Approximately how many files are in myfiles (i.e. the text files)  — 10, 100, 1000? Also, your file opening repeat loop is a bit confused. If you take a look at it on its own (without anything after the first 'end try'), you should see what I mean. As an aside, I generally try to avoid making every variable start with 'the', 'this', 'my', etc… as they tend to obscure what the script is doing.

Comment: Unsure if this is how to reply, but the number of files varies between 20 to 40 at most I guess? I have only been coding for a few months and Applescript isn't my preferred language, so I may be missing a lot of stuff.  So, sorry but, could you elaborate what you mean by the loop being confused? Noted about variables; I usually don't name them like these but looked at a senior's code which was like this so I assumed it's a convention. He's not a coder, so, yeah, thanks for the side note.

Comment: It probably is a convention, just not a very good one. As to how to reply, you should probably update the question to include the approximate number of files. That definitely is a convention here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change the lines between 'tell textedit' to and 'on error' to this:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    repeat with theFile in myFiles
        try
            open theFile
            delay 0.4
            set fileContent to text of document 1
```

And delete the last line of the first repeat loop:

```
set thisFile to thisFile + 1
```

I don't know what your data or spreadsheet look like so I won't comment on them but when I ran the script with some generic text, it seemed to work. At least it moved some text around and completed successfully.

You may not need the `delay 0.4` here but you can test that out. If there is a place for a delay, I would look at placing one immediately after the line in which Excel creates a new workbook — that's probably the most labour-intensive part for the computer.

As for the loop comment… since you are working directly with the list content and not trying to match items in separate lists, you can use `repeat with x in y` with `y` being the list and `x` being each item in the list.

Using `repeat with x from 1 to count of y` really only adds value when you want to get matching items from multiple lists, e.g. `set xx to item x of list1 & item x of list2`. I'm oversimplifying a bit but hopefully making sense.

The confusion part is that the script used `theFile` and `thisFile` for essentially the same thing — both are counting cycles through the loop. However, you also use `theFile` as a file specifier in this line: `set theFile to item thisFile of myFiles`.

Also, the likely reason that you got different error messages is that the try statement obscures things. In this case, the script probably failed to open a text file and thus *fileContent* wasn't set, but since it was inside a try block, it didn't come to light until a later line attempted to use *fileContent*.